# Template Folder in Child Theme for a WooCommerce Extension

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woothemes

I am using **WooCommerce** with a first-party extension called WooCommerce Wishlists.

What I want to achieve is to **customize the template of the wishlist plugin**.

I located the responsible files, but I am not sure about how I have to set up the **folder structure within the child theme**.

Usually, when I override WooCommerce templates, I do it like this:

*wp-content/themes/my-child-theme/woocommerce/template-folder-name/file.php
(i.e. my-child-theme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php)*

In the case of the wishlist plugin, I tried to apply this approach:

The original file structure in the wishlist plugin looks as follows (I am taking the file my-lists.php as an example):

*wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-wishlists/templates/my-lists.php*

So I assume either of the following should work - but it doesn't:

- *wp-content/themes/my-child-theme/woocommerce-wishlists/my-lists.php*
- w*p-content/themes/my-child-theme/woocommerce/woocommerce-wishlists/my-lists.php*
- *wp-content/themes/my-child-theme/woocommerce/wishlists/my-lists.php*

Any suggestions?

---

Note: I can't use hooks here, because they don't exist for the kind of editing I want to do.

Comment: When I used YITH (different plugin, same wishlist feature), they said to use the woocommerce template directory in your theme. `wp-content/themes/my-child-theme/woocommerce`

Comment: Now it works! Thanks